# Dim as Control in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to go over check boxes in a user form and display them in a pivot table according to the user selection

I use the following code:

```
Dim mthIdx As Long
Dim nm As String
Dim c As Control
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(CakePivot2).PivotFields("month")
    For mthIdx = 1 To 12
        nm = "CheckBox" & mthIdx
        Set c = Controls(nm)
        .PivotItems(mthIdx).Visible = printing_rep.c.Value
    Next
End With
```

It works fine when I put it in a user form privete sub but if I'm trying to put it in a different module I get "Sub or function not defined" error and "Controls" is highlighted in the code.
Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what is `Controls()`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Is this what you are trying? `Set c = UserForm1.Controls(nm)`

Comment: Yes this is great! I wrote the user form name (printing_rep) after setting c so moving it up like you suggested fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier reply. I had misunderstood your question. :)

Comment: I have posted an alternate way.. See if that also helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate way (UNTESTED) of what you are trying to accomplish

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim mthIdx As Long
    Dim c As Control
    Dim ID As String

    mthIdx = 0

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotTable1).PivotFields("month")
        For Each c In printing_rep.Controls
            If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
                ID = Replace(c.Name, "CheckBox", "")

                Select Case Val(Trim(ID))
                Case 1 To 12: mthIdx = Val(Trim(ID))
                End Select

                If mthIdx <> 0 Then
                    .PivotItems(mthIdx).Visible = c.Value
                    mthIdx = 0
                End If
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but the library was already added and I can declare c as control so it's not the problem